# unable to click on button with Formik form

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, formik

I am using Formik for my validation such that if the input is empty, I will get a 'required error'.

When I click on the button of my form, a list should be rendered (UsersFoundList). This **list is outside the form** and has elements which further have buttons. When I click on  any of those buttons from the list for the first time, they dont work. Instead, the formik error starts showing up on the input field.

This error should only show up when I am trying to submit the form again. Not when I click on anything else.

```
const [showFlatList, setShowFlatList] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmitForm = (
    values: FormValues,
    helpers: FormikHelpers<FormValues>,
  ) => {
    console.log('hello', values.input)
    setShowFlatList(true);
    helpers.resetForm();
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View >
          <Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
            validationSchema={addRelationValidationSchema}>
            {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
              <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
                <View style={styles.form}>
                  <FieldInput
                    handleChange={handleChange}
                    handleBlur={handleBlur}
                    value={values.input}
                    fieldType="input"
                    icon="user"
                    placeholderText="E-Mail oder Telefonnummer oder Name"
                  />
                  <ErrorMessage
                    name="input"
                    render={(msg) => <ErrorText errorMessage={msg} />}
                  />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                  <NewButton buttonText="Suchen" onPress={handleSubmit} />
                </View>
              </View>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </View>
                <View style={styles.listHolder}>
          {showFlatList && (
            <UsersFoundList/>
          )}
        </View>
    </View>
  );
```

**Reproduced Example:** https://snack.expo.io/@nhammad/jealous-beef-jerky

Noticeable in Android phone. Not on the web version of codesandbox.

Edit: Just realised that not just the button but if I click anywhere on the screen, the error shows up again.

Comment: If the form isn't valid, the `onSubmit` function given to formik never gets called. It gets short circuited because there are validation errors. If you want to do something regardless of form errors or not, then you'll have to move your `showFlatList` out of the onsubmit and call it separately from the `handleSubmit` when the user pushes the button.

Comment: Yes, but the list is outside the Form. I am clicking on a button inside the list, not clicking on the form button so why is handleSubmit being called at all? Please see the codesandbox@Adam

Comment: When I push a button on the users list, the form doesn't get submitted and validation errors aren't showing up, not sure what you mean?

Comment: I can't reproduce this either, sound like an event bubbling problem though.

Comment: On the codesandbox, It's showing the error to me in an android phone. Are you checking on web @sandrooco

Comment: I think what you are seeing is the field is still focused when you push the submit button on android and the error is then showing up on blur of the field - not on submit of the form. The way you want to solve it is to blur the focused field when the form is submitted (use a ref)

Answer (score 0):

In your form, you need to pass a `ref` to your `FieldInput` component

```js
// get a ref for your field input
const fieldRef = useRef();


 const handleSubmitForm = (
    values: FormValues,
    helpers: FormikHelpers<FormValues>,
  ) => {
    // on successful submission blur the field
    fieldRef.current.blur();
    ...
 };

...


   <Form
     ...
     render={() => (
       {/* pass the ref to your fieldinput in your form */}      
       <FieldInput ref={ref} .../>
     )}

   />
```

Then in your custom `FieldInput` component, you need to forward the ref like this:

```js
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

export const FieldInput = forwardRef((props,ref) => {
  return (
    <Item rounded={rounded} style={[styles.inputItem, style]}>
      <Input
         ref={ref}
         ...
      />
    />
  )
});
```

Comment: @Jnl - didn't work is a terrible description, but a quick glance at your commented code looks like you didn't implement the forwardRef properly. `ref` is **NOT** a prop - it is passed to a `forwardRef` component as the second argument (after the props)

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure what you mean by implementing forwardRef. fieldRef.current.blur(); gives Typescript errors and hence I tried using the if statement. I passed this: ref={fieldRef}. But the app's behavior was was still the same as before

Comment: Currently, my fieldInput props are handleChange,
  handleBlur,
  fieldType,
  placeholderText,
 etc. Should I delete all of them and use forwardref only? I have already tried adding ref here.

Comment: Somehow, when I click on any item (UserFoundEntry), the onBlur event is triggered. It shouldn't happen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63706732/how-to-use-useref-with-formik-in-typescript