# How to use useRef with Typescript/Formik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, formik

I am passing a `ref` property into my custom FieldInput that I use for Formik validation of my form. However, it gives a few Typescript errors. For instance, in my function:

```
    const handleSubmitForm = (
    values: FormValues,
    helpers: FormikHelpers<FormValues>,
  ) => {

    setShowFlatList(true);
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    helpers.resetForm();
    if (fieldRef && fieldRef.current){
          fieldRef.current.blur();}
    helpers.resetForm();
  };
```

I get an error on fieldRef.current that `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`. I thought adding the if condition would fix it but it didn't. Also, when I submit the form, I get a warning that

```
Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm()
Error: "fieldRef.current.blur is not a function. (In 'fieldRef.current.blur()', 'fieldRef.current.blur' is undefined)" in handleSubmitForm
```

Similarly, in my custom FieldInput component where I use  `ref={fieldRef}`, I get an error that:

```
Type '{ ref: MutableRefObject<undefined>; setFieldTouched: (field: string, isTouched?: boolean | undefined, shouldValidate?: boolean | undefined) => void; handleChange: { ...; }; ... 4 more ...; placeholderText: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FieldInputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FieldInputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)
```

How can I fix these?

Here's a codesandbox:

https://snack.expo.io/@nhammad/jealous-beef-jerky-fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into current generic types of your `forwardRef` method, first parameter is `unknown`. Just change your signature method of input to

```
export const FieldInput = React.forwardRef<Input, FieldInputProps>(...)
```

Typescript will automatically resolve correct type based on `forwardRef` method return type.

Comment: Yeah I already kinda fixed it: https://snack.expo.io/HI9bdGAxf but I have to use ```any``` instead of ```Input```here ```const fieldRef = useRef<any>(null);```otherwise it gives an inline error on ```fieldRef.current?.blur```. Is there a fix for it?

Comment: @Jnl Just use const fieldRef = useRef<TextInput>(null); (TextInput is imported from 'react-native')